# Is it possible to customize "History" tab for Bug/Task work item types?

Tags: tfs

It could be good to have a work item view that showed the description of that work item plus each comment associated with the item in chronological order. This view could also include links and attachments (mixed in with the comments, in chronological order).

Is it possible to customize "History" tab for Bug/Task work items? How to do that?

P.S. I've tried to Google that, but what I found are OLAP management, different custom TFS reports that display issues number and flows...

Any thoughts are welcome. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We modified our work item templates to show description and history on the same tab.  This was pretty easily accomplished using the TFS Power Tools (links to both the 2008 and 2010 are available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963.aspx)).

Example:

[image: tfs workitem example]

Comment: Robaticus, could you please how you aligned these control as "left" and "right"? In my case they are full page width, description upper, history down... I've tried to change their alignment by "Dock" property (Left-Right, Left-Fill, Left-Left), but seems like it doesn't help... Please advise

Comment: I don't have the XML handy right now (it's still at work, and I'm at home), but basically, in the layout, create a group that contains two columns.  Put the description in one column, and the history in the second.  Your best bet is to use the TFS Power Tools to do your layout editing.

Comment: Thanks! I really needed to create a group with 2 columns :)

Comment: Could you please see a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143749/ui-issue-in-tfs-custom-work-item as it is potentially caused by implemented UI... Please let me know if you have any thoughts about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the history tab by editing the work item template, but you can't change the functionality of the history field itself.  So, without writing your own control to render the content (which would then need to be hosted in an application or plugin outside of TFS), I don't think you could achieve this easily.